# How to reuse a pgfplots table?

Tags: pgfplots

I am creating multiple plots from a single input:

```
\addplot+[discard if not={condition}{T}] table[meta index = {1}, y index = {2}, x index = {3}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot+[discard if not={condition}{F}] table[meta index = {1}, y index = {2}, x index = {3}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
```

How can I avoid this duplication and reuse the table?

```
% create reference to table
...
\addplot+[discard if not={condition}{T}] TableReference
\addplot+[discard if not={condition}{F}] TableReference
```

Comment: `\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\loadedtable` and `\addplot table {\loadedtable};`.

Comment: Wouldn't that still require defining the same table settings for each plot? [meta index = {1}, y index = {2}, x index = {3}, col sep=comma]

Comment: Yes, it does.  You can look it up in the [pgfplots manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf).  This is also where I got the `\pgfplotstableread` trick from.

Comment: yeah, but that's what I am trying to avoid, as shown in the above example

Comment: Then do `\tikzset{preset/.style = {meta index = {1}, y index = {2}, x index = {3}, col sep=comma}}` and `\addplot table[preset] {\loadedtable};`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Would you like to add an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments